# Drag and drop from ftp client to web browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ftp, drag-and-drop

I am using nautilus as an ftp client, and when dragging files to the web browser (tried on chromium, chrome and firefox) no files are received by the drag and drop library.
Is there some sort of security thing that blocks this feature in web browsers? Or this this a client related issue? Or maybe the drag and drop library (I am using ng-dropzone with angularjs).

Comment: If it is a library issue, F12 could show some console message. If not, then this likely belongs on superuser or similar

Comment: F12 shows that the library doesn't even acknowledge that the file is uploaded